# Tapping push notifications from the Android app just takes me to my feed

Tags: feature-request, android-app, notifications

When I receive push notifications from the StackExchange app, my expectation that tapping them should take me to the post on which the notification happened is always violated. It seems wrong to me that tapping a push notification should just do the same thing as opening the app the normal way.

I would like to request that tapping a push notification from the Android app should bring the user to the post that generated the notification.  If the user has multiple inbox messages, at least open the inbox.

Comment: This is a bug, it should be taking you to the actual page. Looking into it now.